# zoom in / zoom out of text in UIWebView using IBAction

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, zooming

I am trying to zoom in and zoom out the text in UIWebView, 
I have a function that I used to zoom for the UITextView which is:

```
    - (IBAction)ZoomOutFunction{
    @try {

        UIFont *font = self.detailTextView.font;

        if(self.detailTextView.font == [font fontWithSize:13])
            self.detailTextView.font = [font fontWithSize:13];
        else
            self.detailTextView.font = [font fontWithSize:font.pointSize-1];

    }@catch (NSException *err) {
        NSLog(@"Error handler : %@", err);

    }
}
```

I want to add/subtract the font (one size) every time I click on the button I have two buttons (one for zooming in and other for zooming out).

The function above doesn't work with UIWebView, so what shall I adjust in this function to work with the UIWebView.

Thank you,

Comment: Why are you using try catch block?
fatima your logic for code is okay but dint you get any syntax error? 
if(self.detailTextView.font == [font fontWithSize:13]){
            self.detailTextView.font = [font fontWithSize:20];
}
else
self.detailTextView.font = [font fontWithSize:font.pointSize-1];
check this out. phir btayen

Answer (score 1):

Try this line of code:

```
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

Comment: I want to add/subtract the font (one size) every time I click on the button I have two buttons (one for zooming in and other for zooming out)

Comment: @Fatima Yes but with this code the user can zoom in/and out by pinching.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique no the code above doesn't provide zoom in/out by pinching, it provides it using IBaction and two UIBarButtons (one for zoom in and second for zoom out)

Comment: @Fatima This code: [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES]; provides for pinching

Comment: @AbdullahShafique  yes what you gave it to me provides for pinching, but I don't want it, I want it using IBActions

Answer (score 1):

Try methods given below.
As webview is also subclass of scrollview, its scrollview can be zoomed both by gestures and action.

//zoom in button action

*

```
- (IBAction)zoomIn:(id)sender {
    if(_webVIewLyrics.scrollView.zoomScale < _webVIewLyrics.scrollView.maximumZoomScale) {
        _webVIewLyrics.scrollView.zoomScale = (_webVIewLyrics.scrollView.zoomScale + 0.15);
    }
}
//zoom out button action
- (IBAction)zoomOut:(id)sender {
    if(_webVIewLyrics.scrollView.zoomScale > _webVIewLyrics.scrollView.minimumZoomScale) {
        _webVIewLyrics.scrollView.zoomScale = (_webVIewLyrics.scrollView.zoomScale - 0.15);
    }
}
```

Hope this helped :)